# 12.04 HP notebook becomes very hot

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP Pavillion dv6 1330er. And when I work with text editor or some other programs, it becomes very hot, but processor works between 10%.

How can I solve this problem? Install some softwares or what? Please help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t) type `lspci` and then `top -n 1` and add the outputs to the question. The first command will give us general idea about the hardware, the second will show what's hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's propably your gpu card that's getting hot. Ubuntu uses the open-source radeon driver for the amd cards. It's a relatively good driver but it doesn't support automatic power-management and so your car is working full-power unless you set a power-level yourself.

Since you have a good laptop and want to fully take advantage of your hardware, I would suggest that you install amd's catalyst proprietary driver.

system settings--> Additional-drivers and select ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics drivers. Once the installation is complete you must restart you computer in order for the driver to be activated.

Comment: And can you get me some link how to do this, because in additional drivers I don't have this

Comment: Propably the "restricted" repository is deactivated.
Open the ubuntu soft center--->edit--->software sources--> make sure all the first 4 choices are ticked. Close it and open the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx`

and reboot.

Comment: all is good but the resolution is only 1024x768, and I have 1366x768. How I can set this?

Comment: open the AMD Catalyst Control Center (administraive) , go to screen management and choose your monitors native resolution from there.

Comment: I can't launch if because it had some error wile installation. How I can uninstall well that driver? And install new driver?

Comment: open termina and type:

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge fglrx*`

and reboot

Comment: And how I can remove old ati driver, becuese when I typed  'sudo apt-get autoremove --purge fglrx*' and rebooted and than started to install ati driver. In the end of installation appear error that 'fglrx' driver is alredy in file system?